# How do I pass a property from a razor page model to asp-route-id tag helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

So I am using asp.net razor pages and I want to pass a property from one of my page models to be used in the asp-route-id tag helper in the _layout page. I tried injecting the specific page model onto the _layout page and accessing it through @Model tag, when i use this and hover over the nav bar, the route id i want to show comes up, but when i click on it i get this error:

[image]

and if I use viewdata, it disappears after clicking on a nav item and becomes null.

**_layout.cshtml(shared)**

```
@model VescovererWebApp.Pages.AccountModel


<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - VescovererWebApp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index"><img id="logo" src="~/Logo/vescoverer.png" /></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                    <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a id="cu" class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Account" asp-route-id="@Model.currentUserID">Account</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Vescover" asp-route-id="@Model.currentUserID">Vescover</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Vescovered" asp-route-id="@Model.currentUserID">Vescovered</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Verify" asp-route-id="@Model.currentUserID">Verify</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2021 - VescovererWebApp - <a asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>

<style>
    #logo {
        height: 40px;
        width: 40px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use AccountModel as a base class

```
public class VescoveredModel : AccountModel
```

or you can create interface IAccountModel

```
public class AccountModel:IAccountModel
```

and

```
public class VescoveredModel : IAccountModel
```

and change layout model

```
@model VescovererWebApp.Pages.IAccountModel
```

Comment: Much appreciated sir, was stuck on this for ages

Answer (score 0):

you have two chose:

**1.with button**

```
<form method="post" asp-page="Order" asp-page-handler="Details">
<input type="hidden" name="Id" value="@item.Id">
<input type="submit" value="Show" >
</form>
```

**2.with tag a**

add `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` to `_ViewImports.cshtml`

and use

```
<a asp-page="/Supplier" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Click</a>
```